# ckeditor - ENTER key disabled in source mode

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I am working with a CMS which is using ckeditor. I need to work mainly in source mode.

The problem is, the ENTER key is deactivated (only in source mode). I need the enter key to realign code, create new spaces between elements, etc. So basically I would need the ENTER key to do exactly what the ENTER key in a TXT file does. Just creating a new line without having any content (or tag) in it.

Any idea how I can activate the enter key? I have seen it works in ckeditor demos. However, the CMS I am working in had it already implemented and I guess the button was deactivated for source mode editing. I just can't figure out how I can reactivate it in the config file.

Answer (score 0):

When using a source mode, the content area is plain `textarea` where `Enter` key works by default. There are also no iframes in source mode (contrary to editing mode) thus all is in the same document.

Most likely there is some key listener added which blocks enter keys for editor `textarea` or all `textarea` on page and in order to allow enters you would need to remove it.